How to fix gdbpeda
I'm using WSL and already installed gdb and gdbpeda using apt install. I even git cloned gdb peda. But when I run gdb, gdb-peda is now showing, rather than it shows multiple errors. I installed six too.
head part
tail part
I also tried to use pwndbg but it got same result.
